# ASP .NET Web API: What is the best place to initialize collection by using database data?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have ASP .NET Web API application. One of my controllers use `EmailNotificationService`. This service is responsible for sending email to other users and injected in controller by `Unity`. Email templates store in a database. So I am looking for a way to fetch this templates at once. I do not want to perform database requests in the `EmailNotificationService` constructor. It should be responsible for creating object not for getting data. What is the base practices for this case? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I agree that database calls shouldn't happen in a constructor.  Presumably you're calling a method on `EmailNotificationService` which sends the email, and that method knows what template it should use?  Can't that method get the template from the database?  I imagine there's some interface from which it can get the template, and that interface can be supplied to the method or injected into `EmailNotificationService` via its constructor.

Comment: You should inject a IEmailTemplateDataStore into your EmailNotificationService.  This will have a .GetAllTemplates() method I guess. (And eventually a concrete EmailTemplateDataStore that hits the db.  Internal to EmailNotificationService, create a private property. also create a private member ICollection<MyTemplate> _templates.   in the "get" of the Property, check for a null or non null _templates.  if null, hit your injected IEmailTemplateDataStore to populate _templates.

Comment: @David I am going to send a lot of emails. So I think that it is a good idea to fetch all email templates before all. I do not want to get a call to my database to get single template each time I want to send email.

Comment: @JosephKatzman: Will all of those emails be sent by the same instance of `EmailNotificationService`?  It can have a private property or method containing the templates which defaults an null and fetches/stores the templates when first accessed.  So any time it's accessed it checks if it already has the templates and, if not, fetches and stores them.  Basically a lazy-loaded property.  Then the method just accesses that property any time it sends an email.  The first access fetches the templates, subsequent accesses use the already-fetched templates.

Comment: @David Yes, I through about it. But I do not want to check does email template collection has elements or not every time. The ideal case is to get single call to database without checking the collection every time I need a template.

Comment: @JosephKatzman: Then I guess you'd need to invoke an initializer method on your `EmailNotificationService` once you get it but before you use it.  That method would fetch the templates.  The trade-off, of course, is that any consuming code would have to remember to always invoke that method first.  Since you don't want the emailing method(s) to have to invoke it internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public interface IEmailTemplateDataStore()
{
    ICollection<MyTemplate> GetAllTemplates();
}
```

and

```
public EmailNotificationService : IEmailNotificationService
{

    private readonly IEmailTemplateDataStore EmailTemplateDataStore;

    public EmailNotificationService(IEmailTemplateDataStore ietds)

        this.EmailTemplateDataStore = ietds;

    }

    private ICollection<MyTemplate> _templates;

    private ICollection<MyTemplate> Templates
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == this._templates)
            {
                this._templates = this.EmailTemplateDataStore.GetAllTemplates(); /* if null, populate */

                if (null == this._templates)
                {
                    throw new NullReferenceException("EmailTemplateDataStore.GetAllTemplates returned null");
                }
            }

            return this._templates;
        }
    }

    public DoSomethingOne()
    {
            ICollection<MyTemplate> temps = this.Templates;
            foreach (MyTemplate temp in temps)
            {

            }
    }

    public DoSomethingTwo()
    {
            ICollection<MyTemplate> temps = this.Templates;
            foreach (MyTemplate temp in temps)
            {

            }
    }

}
```